# How can I pass a list to a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I would like to change my function in a class. My function is below :

```
import React from "react";

const selectchoice = ({list}) => (
    <select onChange={} className="custom-select">{list.map(option => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>))}
    </select>
);

export default selectchoice;
```

I tried this :

```
class Select extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                ({this.props.list}) => (
    <select onChange={} className="custom-select">{this.props.list.map(option => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>))}
    </select>
)
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Select;
```

But it does not work unfortunately.

Could you help me please ?

NB : I precise list is such as :

```
listexample: [
            {value: "1", name: "Hello"},
            {value: "2", name: "Hi"},
        ]
```

Comment: _"it does not work"_ - do you get any error? Please describe the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating. The `render` of a class component is identical to the body of a function component (if not using Hooks, which you aren't), except that it takes no argument, with the `props` argument of the function component becoming `this.props`.

So you just want this:

```
class Select extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <select onChange={} className="custom-select">{this.props.list.map(option => (
                <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>))}
            </select>
        ) 
    }
}
```

PS it's not clear why you want to change your function component to a class. Components such as yours, which simply render something dependent only on the props, are generally better left as functions. And if you want to add more complex functionality to your component, like state and "side effects", while these would have needed a class in the past, in modern React they can (and probably should) be done with Hooks in a function component.